# Avoid providing verification code request for specific time using Google authenticator

Tags: authentication, pam, two-factor-authentication

I've just activated the two factor authentication using Google authenticator and I'm now required to provide the verification code any time that I'm logging to the system. How to avoid the authentication step for example 10 hours or until reboot a system after provided verification code? Is it possible?

Comment: Where did you apply the Google authnticator?

Comment: On my Ubuntu, for logging and for sudo. I'm looking for solution through google but nothing found.